# Bootstrap 4 spacing problem in grid system

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am new in bootstrap.

### 1st Problem

I need to make bigger gap between columns in bootstrap but problem is, i don't understand it. Documentation is prefect but not for me :(

I tried to change numbers in col to equal 12 but there were no change
and i noticed that it only changed in phone resolution.

**Desktop**

[image: Computer resolution:]

**Mobile**

[image: Phone resolution:]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
   <div class="row border border-primary">
      <div class="col-md-3 border border-secondary">
         <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>meradla/add" class="btn btn-primary">Pridať</a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-5 border border-success"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4 border border-danger">
      <?= form_open_multipart('meradla/search', ['class' => 'form-inline']); ?>
      <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Priezvisko" name="search" aria-label="Search" style="margin-right:10px">
      <?= form_submit(['class' => 'btn btn-primary'], 'Hľadať'); ?>
      <?= form_close();?>
   </div>
</div>
```

### 2nd Problem

I need to stretch `form-control`, on computer it's ok but i want to stretch it only on tablet and mobile resolution.

**Desktop**

[image: Half computer monitor resolution:]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="row text-center">      
        <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-4">   
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="czakazky">Číslo zákazky</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="czakazky" placeholder="Číslo zákazky">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="poz">Pozícia</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="poz" id="poz" placeholder="Pozícia">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pcislo">Poradové číslo dielu</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pcislo" placeholder="Poradové číslo dielu">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I can't add whole code. Sorry**

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1st Solution

> I need to make bigger gap between columns in bootstrap but problem is, i don't understand it.

Simply remove `container` from your code, `container` sets the content's margins dealing with the responsive behaviors of your layout and `container` remove in small resolution.

for that whenever you change your code in your project, its apply in only small resolution.

```
<div style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="row border border-primary">
        <div class="col-md-3 border border-secondary">
            <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>meradla/add" class="btn btn-primary">Pridať</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 border border-success"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 border border-danger">
            <?= form_open_multipart('meradla/search', ['class' => 'form-inline']); ?>
            <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Priezvisko" name="search" aria-label="Search" style="margin-right:10px">
            <?= form_submit(['class' => 'btn btn-primary'], 'Hľadať'); ?>
            <?= form_close();?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### 2nd Solution

> I need to stretch form-control, on computer it's ok but i want to stretch it only on tablet and mobile resolution.

if you want to apply `col` only in below 992px ( tablet, mobile resolution ) you can use `col-*` to `col-md-*`

I added `col-6` ( 6 column ) in smaller resolution and for larger resolution i added `col-lg-12` ( full width 12 column ) and for `center` i `removed` <strike>offset-md-4</strike> and added `flexbox` css `d-flex flex-column align-items-center`

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="row text-center d-flex flex-column align-items-center">      
        <div class="col-6 col-lg-12">   
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="czakazky">Číslo zákazky</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="czakazky" placeholder="Číslo zákazky">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="poz">Pozícia</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="poz" id="poz" placeholder="Pozícia">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pcislo">Poradové číslo dielu</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pcislo" placeholder="Poradové číslo dielu">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**LIVE SNIPPET**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <div class="row text-center d-flex flex-column align-items-center">      
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-12">   
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="czakazky">Číslo zákazky</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="czakazky" placeholder="Číslo zákazky">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="poz">Pozícia</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="poz" id="poz" placeholder="Pozícia">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pcislo">Poradové číslo dielu</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pcislo" placeholder="Poradové číslo dielu">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dont forgot to consider upvote and select answe as best answer for you by clicking on green arrow !